# Proving that the image of the tangent map is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Euclidean spaces and consider the tangent map of a smooth map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $T_p f: T_pX \rightarrow T_{f(p)}Y$, defined by $(p, v) \mapsto (f(p), \partial f(p)v)$. The author of the text I am reading claims that the image of the tangent map is a subspace of $T_{f(p)}Y$ for the following reason:

*Because $v \mapsto  f(p) + \partial f(p)v$ approximates (up to first order) the map $f$ at the point $p$ when $v$ is in a null neighborhood of $\mathbb{R^n}$ we know that $Im(T_pf)$ is a vector subspace of $T_{f(p)}Y$, which approximates (to first order) $f(X)$ at the point $f(P)$*

If fail to understand why it is necessary to invoke a Taylor expansion to show that the image is a subspace and, moreover, how this argument actually proves that it is a subspace in any event. I'm sure I'm missing something, but showing that $Im(T_pf)$ is a subspace seems to me to be just an easy exercise in applying the linearity of the derivative of $f$ at $p$. E.G., for two points in $T_{f(p)}Y$ we have

$$
(f(p), \partial f(p) u) + (f(p), \partial f(p) v) = (f(p), \partial f(p)u + \partial f(p)v) = T_pf(u+v) \in Im(T_p f)
$$

Homogeneity is just as easy. So my questions are one, *What point is the author trying to make by the provided argument* and two, *If my argument is not correct where does it fail*?

Comment: What do you mean by " a null neighborhood of $R^n$"? Is it just a translate of a neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: @gary A "null neighborhood" is a neighborhood of 0

Comment: I don't think the author wants to prove that the image of the tangent map in $p$ is a subspace. I guess that the key phrase in what you've quote there is that the image of the tangent maps APPROXIMATES $f(X)$ around the point $f(P)$. The tangent map is linear, the tangent space is a linear space, and therefore the image of a linear space is a linear space.

Comment: @Beni You may be right but, if so, it's a terribly unclear statement.